# Swift 3 Firebase Database Fetch URLString

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

By using Firebase database I'm trying update this old code's URL String by RealTime, because the url sometimes goes bad and i have to update it as soon as possible. I have tried some theories which none of them were being processed correctly. except for the below code.. which if the link were to be broken id have no RealTime access to update it.. I need help making a code that will update it RealTime.

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://imageshack.com/i/plyd7Ztkp"><img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/921/yd7Ztk.png" border="0"></a>
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://imageshack.com/i/plMFPoMRp"><img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/921/MFPoMR.png" border="0"></a>
```

From the picture above, if i were to change from "www.google.com" to any other URL it should update the webView also.

I hope I'm clear enough of what I'm trying to accomplish

```
@IBAction func zhwandoontv(_ sender: Any) {

    webView.frame=self.view.bounds;
    webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
    webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;

    let tolourl = URL(string: "http://38.99.146.180:7777/Zhwandoon.m3u8?user=sgls128196012&session=a9a822ced3f0211c85d67487a252d6497bef40a6bd64e0f01c332de5c9369")
    let toloURLRequest = URLRequest(url: tolourl!)
    webView.loadRequest(toloURLRequest)

}
```

Update:

```
}

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle:FIRDatabaseHandle?

var postData = [String]()


@IBAction func Bahartv(_ sender: Any) {

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


    databaseHandle = ref?.child("realtimeURL").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let post = snapshot.value as? String

        if let actualPost = post {
            self.postData.append(actualPost)

        }
    })


    webView.frame=self.view.bounds;
    webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
    webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;

    let tolourl = self.postData.append(actualPost)
    let toloURLRequest = URLRequest(url: tolourl!)
    webView.loadRequest(tolourl)

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    databaseHandle = ref?.child("realtimeURL").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let post = snapshot.value as? String

        if let actualPost = post {
            self.postData.append(actualPost)

        }
    })

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

Comment: Anyone? Thank you sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got your back.
Now, I'm assuming the problem is that you want to change your URL whenever it goes down in real-time, and you don't know how to use Firebase.

For this, I recommend you read this document from Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

You can also do it step by step like this:

1. Create a project on Firebase, import it into your iOS Project.
2. Create a node on Firebase realtime database, called realtimeURL.
3. Go to your zhwandoontv function, listen to the realtimeURL changes, then pass it to the request.
4. Refresh the request as well as your webView. Well done.

**Update:**
Base on your code, I can adjust the code like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle:FIRDatabaseHandle?

func loadWebViewWithURL(url: String) {
    webView.frame=self.view.bounds;
    webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
    webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;

    let toloURLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.loadRequest(tolourl)
}

func initDatabaseHandle() {
    if ref == nil {
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }

    databaseHandle = ref?.child("realtimeURL").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let post = snapshot.value as? String
        {
            self.loadWebViewWithURL(post)
        }
    })
}

@IBAction func Bahartv(_ sender: Any) {
    if databaseHandle == nil {
        // re-init the handle
        initDatabaseHandle()
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    initDatabaseHandle()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the Step by Step, Could you explain it in code ? if possible. i know you have my back !

Comment: Hmm, code gives no errors, but i notice that when i press the function button. The webview doesn't load it, like nothing appears.

Comment: I just adjusted it based on your code. What I wanna show you here was that you only need to listen to the changes one time (at the first).

Comment: While playing around with the code, i have figured it out! and it works like a charm! Thank you Xuan! owe you big time buddy!!

Comment: Glad to hear that byddy! :)